# @types in subfolder node_modules not being picked up by jest

Tags: typescript, types, jestjs, ts-jest

I have the following folder structure

--Services

----Service1

----Service2

Service1 and Service2 are separate node projects with their own package.json.  Services is again another node project with its own package.json.  From within Service1 I am writing unit tests and install @types/jest.  So now my folder structure is

--Services

----Service1

------node_modules

--------@types

----------jest

----Service2

When I try to write an unit test for Service1 I get an error for describe is not defined.  From the tsconfig documentation

"By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible;"

However if I install @types/jest at the "Services" level then it seems to pick up fine.  I have not specified "typeRoots" or "types" in any of the services.

Comment: do you have test.ts files in exclude in tsconfig.json? I removed from mine and jest typing worked again